# Missing Left Parenthesis - I see no error

Tags: sql

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, but I haven't come to a solution, could you please help me? I have four tables like this, I think the problem may be the foreign keys?

I am using SQL+ (Oracle) and SQL Developer.

This is my code:

```
create table doctor(
doctor_id int constraint nn_name not null,
fname varchar2(30),
lname varchar2(30),
address varchar2(30),
phone_no number(30),
email varchar2(30),
experience_years number(10),
grade number(10),
specialities varchar(30),
availabilty_date default sysdate,
agency_id int,
foreign key references agency (agency_id);
```

Comment: You are missing `)` at the end. In Place of `;` use `)`

Comment: foreign key references agency (agency_id));

You need 2 paranthesis at the end

Comment: And you need to list the fk columns `foreign key (agency_id) references ...`

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says: you need one more `)`.

The `create table (` does not get closed at the end. There were also some other bugs I fixed:

```
create table doctor
( doctor_id int constraint nn_name not null,
  fname varchar2(30),
  lname varchar2(30),
  address varchar2(30),
  phone_no number(30),
  email varchar2(30),
  experience_years number(10),
  grade number(10),
  specialities varchar(30),
  availabilty_date date default sysdate, -- missing data type
  agency_id int,
  constraint agency_fk foreign key (agency_id) references agent (agency_id) -- invalid foreign constraint
) -- this one
```

Comment: @user3480458: Need more help?